# Metro Bundler does not start (MacOS)

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I installed React Native following the requirements in the documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) , i got all the simulators working but i have to manually open them everytime i open the project.

If i press m after npm start the following error shows "warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed."

(Btw this is my first time using React-Native so sorry if this is a rookie mistake)

Does anyone know any solution ?

Comment: The message you're referencing says more accurately that React Native can't _find_ Metro running. What does Metro output when you actually run it? (PS, we're all React Native rookies)

Comment: i don't know what was the output before but i used npm update because i found that some modules i had previously installed were outdated, after using npm update now i can open the emulator using the terminal still cannot open it in the browser but at least i do not have to open Xcode and Android Studio everytime i want to work. I also got access to the dev menu and the error is not showing anymore the same happened for the debugger.

Comment: Try npx react-native run-ios (or run-android). If you have xcode/android studio properly installed, the simulator should launch during the execution process.